# Border around CSS background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to draw a border around a CSS background image, which resizes itself according to window size in a container div. I can draw a border around the div, but not around the image itself.

Can this even be done in this kind of setup?

Rather than post code here, I've made a working example [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJJdNL)

```
<style parse-style>#pimg {
background:#FFF url( {{ img }} ) center center no-repeat;  
background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;;}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would consider adding a div to contain your background image then a a border to this div.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLexgG)?

Comment: No, Chris, I can do that, but I want the border to be only around the image and not the entire div.

Comment: @angularchobo, in that case it isn't possible **with your current markup**. You can achieve this however, if you're willing to change it slightly?

Comment: Of course, as long as the image resizes in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that. You could add a second div that contains the image, but then you wouldn't be able to use background-size: contain.

If you knew that the image dimensions wouldn't change, you could add a second background-image, positioned in the same way, that was simply a transparent png with the border you wanted... but that would be really silly.

Comment: Thanks, yes I need background-size: contain and the images always have the same proportion. I thought of something along these lines, but thought it was silly and possibly might lead to complications down the road.

Comment: If you're willing to change the markup, you could simply place the image as an img tag, and use max-width and max-height to handle the resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have the time to create a working example right now, but a possible workaround may be the use of multiple backgrounds: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

The second background could be an SVG rectangle with a stroke. To avoid possible stroke deformation due to scaling, use non-scaling stroke: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke

Answer (score 0):

As shipshape said, there's no way to draw border for BG image but I got an idea which may help you. You can use 2 background images and the behind one can be a plaint colored background playing role of the border. See the code below:

```
#pimg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url({{ bg-image.jpg }}), url({{ 1px.jpg }});
  background-size: 90% 90%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: center center, left top;
}
```

Use 1x1px shim image in your desired color as the border and repeat it.
The background size can control the width of the border. If you increase 90%, the border will be thinner and if you decrease it, the border will be wider.